# TCP KEEP ALIVE Ack not seen for some duration

Tags: tcp, linux-kernel, network-programming, tcp-keepalive

I have a TCP application running on linux. I have SO_KEEPALIVE option set for my TCP connection.
Here are the my setting.

```
static const int KEEPALIVE_ENABLE = 1;
static const int KEEPALIVE_IDLE_TIME = 1; // 5s
static const int KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL =  1; // 1s
static const int KEEPALIVE_COUNT = 3;
```

My system(A) will be getting tcp keep alive for every 1 from other system(B) if system(B) doesn't get ack for 3 probe count it's going to reset the connection.
question: sometimes what I observed is tcp keep alive ack is not sent(sometimes),du to this connection is getting reset.
could somebody tell me what could be the possible reason for not sending this tcp keep alive ack?